# Necessary and sufficient conditions for uniqueness of solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

Consider the following linear system of equations
$$
A^\top y=(A^\top A) x
$$
with unknown $x$, where
$$
A\equiv \left[\begin{array}{ccc|cccc|cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & p_1 & 0 & 0   &  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & p_2   & 0 & 0 & 0 &  1   & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & p_3   & 0 & 0 & 0 &  1   & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & p_4 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & p_5 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & p_6 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & p_7 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & p_8 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & p_9 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & p_{10} &  0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0& p_{11}  & 0 & 0 &  0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & p_{12} & 0 & 0 &  0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}\right]
$$

The $p$'s in the central block are strictly positive, but potentially equal among each other.

**Question:** I would like to find necessary and sufficient conditions such that the system has a unique solution wrto $x$.

---

In what follows, for every $t=1,...,12$, I will refer to $t_1$ as the position of the first "1" in row $t$ and $t_2$ as the position of the "p" in row $t$.

---

I have found some **sufficient** conditions:

(1) Anyone element of $x$ is set equal to a known number by the analyst. For example, $x_1=0$.

(2) For every $j\in \{4,5,6,7\}$, there are at least two rows $t,\tau$ such that $t_1=\tau_1$, $t_2=\tau_2=j$, and $p_t\neq p_{\tau}$.

Note that (2) is not necessary. For example, delete the $4$-th row of $A$ and impose (1). Then, the system has a unique solution.

---

I have found some **necessary** conditions.

Necessary conditions are:

(1) Anyone element of $x$ is set equal to a known number by the analyst. For example, $x_1=0$.

(2) For $j=4,5,6,7$, column $j$ has at least two distinct strictly positive elements.

Comment: $A$ has 11 columns and 10 rows, so it CANNOT have full column rank

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I have added tow rows.

Comment: The sum of the first 3 columns is equal to the sum of the last 4, so it has never full rank

Comment: Thanks again. You are totally right, I have reformulated my question. Also, in line with your point, see necessary condition (1)

Comment: the matrix $A^TA$ is always singular, so NO condition is sufficient, and ANY condition is necessary